# Error in a JNDI Configuration in Grails

Tags: tomcat, grails, jndi

I am trying to deploy a Grailsn (1.3.7) Webapp to Tomcat 7.023 and use JNDI.

I added the next code to *conf/Config.groovy*

```
grails.naming.entries = [
        "jdbc/turismoenguada": [
                type: "javax.sql.DataSource",
                auth: "Container",
                url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/turismoenguada",
                driverClassName: "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver",
                description: "Development Datasource",
                username: "turismoenguada",
                password: "mypassword",
                maxActive: "8",
                maxIdle: "4"
        ]
]
```

My *conf/DataSource.groovy* has the production configuration as follows:

```
  production {
        dataSource {
            pooled = false
            dbCreate = "update"
            jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/turismoenguada"
        }
    }
```

My tomcat/conf/server.xml has the Host:

```
<Host name="turismoenguadalajara" appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="" docBase="TurismoEnGuadalajara-0.1" debug="0">
        <Resource
                name="jdbc/turismoenguada"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="turismoenguada"
            password="mypassword"
                driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/turismoenguada"/>
    </Context>
</Host>
```

When i start tomcat I get the next error:

```
2011-12-11 21:24:37,673 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
2011-12-11 21:24:37,676 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR [/TurismoEnGuadalajara-0.1]  - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Dec 11, 2011 9:24:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Dec 11, 2011 9:24:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/TurismoEnGuadalajara-0.1] startup failed due to previous errors
2011-12-11 21:24:37,686 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR [/TurismoEnGuadalajara-0.1]  - Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'jdbcUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'jdbcUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 6 more
```

If anyone can help, I really appreciate it!